# How to build Poco Single Threaded library on Linux

Tags: poco-libraries

How to build Poco 1.11.7 Single Threaded library on Linux?

I successfully built the Poco single-threaded library for the older version 1.9.4 by editing the build/config/Linux file and removing the following syntax:

- "-D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE" from SYSFLAGS
- "-lpthread" from SYSLIBS

However, when applying the same changes to Poco 1.11.7, it doesn't result in a single-threaded library. Instead, it always compiles with the pthread library.

I would like to inquire if there is any other way to build the Poco single-threaded library for version 1.11.7.